# Cannot call rusqlite's query because it expects the type &[&rusqlite::types::ToSql]

Tags: rust, traits

I want to use a prepared statement with [rusqlite](https://github.com/jgallagher/rusqlite). Rusqlite implements the trait `ToSql` for `String`, `&str` and [a bunch of other types](https://github.com/jgallagher/rusqlite/blob/master/src/types/to_sql.rs):

```
extern crate rusqlite;

use rusqlite::Connection;

fn main() {
    let mut connection = Connection::open("C:\\test_db.db").unwrap();

    let mut cached_statement = connection
        .prepare_cached("SELECT ?, ?, ? FROM test")
        .unwrap();

    let vec_values = vec![
        &"test1".to_string(),
        &"test2".to_string(),
        &"test3".to_string(),
    ];

    let rows = cached_statement.query(vec_values.as_slice()).unwrap();
}
```

This does not compile with the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:18:39
   |
18 |     let rows = cached_statement.query(vec_values.as_slice()).unwrap();
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait rusqlite::types::ToSql, found struct `std::string::String`
   |
   = note: expected type `&[&rusqlite::types::ToSql]`
              found type `&[&std::string::String]`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler message isn't lying to you. You have a `&[&String]` not a `&[&ToSql]`. A *trait object* is a different type and often a different size from the underlying type; both are important considerations when packing values into a vector.

Another problem is that you cannot create a `String`, take a reference to it, then store that in a variable. The `String` would be deallocated immediately, leaving a dangling reference, so the compiler prevents that.

The easiest thing you can do is to create a new `Vec` that contains the trait object references:

```rust
let vec_values = vec![
    "test1".to_string(),
    "test2".to_string(),
    "test3".to_string(),
];

let query_values: Vec<_> = vec_values.iter().map(|x| x as &dyn ToSql).collect();

let _rows = cached_statement.query(&query_values).unwrap();
```

([complete example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e4a723a91a36aac82b6498bde06ba786))

Or if you wanted an overly-generic function to perform the conversion:

```rust
fn do_the_thing<'a, I, T: 'a>(things: I) -> Vec<&'a dyn ToSql>
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = &'a T>,
    T: ToSql,
{
    things.into_iter().map(|x| x as &dyn ToSql).collect()
}
```

```rust
let _rows = cached_statement.query(&do_the_thing(&vec_values)).unwrap();
```

([complete example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f6919344afad7aecfd823b095042a653))

In many cases, you can use the [`params!`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.24.1/rusqlite/macro.params.html) or [`named_params!`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.24.1/rusqlite/macro.named_params.html) macro:

```rust
let a = "test1".to_string();
let b = "test2".to_string();
let c = "test3".to_string();

let _rows = cached_statement.query(params![a, b, c]).unwrap();
```

([complete example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f6919344afad7aecfd823b095042a653))

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. This does not work because "std::convert::From<&std::string::String>"  is not implemented for "rusqlite::types::ToSqlOutput<'_>" I have not tried the generic solution, but since its basically the same code it should result in the same error. ( x as &ToSql      is the problem)

Comment: @SlaterTh I don't know what you mean. Both pieces of code that I have posted compile successfully and I've now added links to the entire compilable examples. I'm guessing that one of us has added or removed something without explicitly mentioning it.

Comment: Your code is indeed correct, I used &String inside the vec.... Thank you for your time.