# Why does Rusqlite reject the Option type when executing a query?

Tags: sqlite, rust

I'm trying to insert CSV data into a SQLite database. `stripe_id` is optional, and so its type is `Option<&str>`. All the other fields are `&str`. When I use `conn.execute` to insert the values, they all insert correctly except for `stripe_id`, which throws an error saying it expects `&str` and not `Option`.

I've searched the docs and `Option<T>` implements `ToSQL`, and when I've tried replacing my code with the Rusqlite example that includes an `Option` value, it throws the same error for the example code.

The relevant struct and query code snippet:

```rust
struct Merchant<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    billing_portal: &'a str,
    billing_period: &'a str,
    stripe_id: Option<&'a str>,
}
```

```rust
conn.execute(
    "INSERT INTO merchants (name, billing_portal, billing_period, stripe_id)
     values (?, ?, ?, ?)",
     &[&merch.name, &merch.billing_portal, &merch.billing_period, &merch.stripe_id]
).expect("Error inserting merchant into database");
```

The error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:38:75
   |
38 |              &[&merch.name, &merch.billing_portal, &merch.billing_period, &merch.stripe_id]
   |                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `&str`, found enum `std::option::Option`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&&str`
              found reference `&std::option::Option<&str>`
```

And the complete code:

```rust
extern crate csv;
extern crate rusqlite;

use rusqlite::{Connection, Result};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Merchant<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    billing_portal: &'a str,
    billing_period: &'a str,
    stripe_id: Option<&'a str>,
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let conn = Connection::open("data.sqlite")?;

    let mut reader = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
                                        .has_headers(false)
                                        .from_path("merchants.csv")
                                        .expect("Failed to read csv");
    for record in reader.records() {
        let record = record.unwrap();
        let merch = Merchant {
            name: &record[0],
            billing_portal: &record[3],
            billing_period: &record[4],
            stripe_id: (match &record[5] {
                x if x == "" => None,
                x            => Some(x)
            }),
        };
        println!("{:?}", &merch);

        conn.execute(
            "INSERT INTO merchants (name, billing_portal, billing_period, stripe_id)
             values (?, ?, ?, ?)",
             &[&merch.name, &merch.billing_portal, &merch.billing_period, &merch.stripe_id]
        ).expect("Error inserting merchant into database");

    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Cannot call rusqlite's query because it expects the type &\[&rusqlite::types::ToSql\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46624591/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR the duplicate: `&[&merch.name as &ToSql, &merch.billing_portal as &ToSql, &merch.billing_period as &ToSql, &merch.stripe_id as &ToSql]`

Comment: In the future, please include a [MRE]. This error doesn't require any CSV-related code to reproduce. It will make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: [An example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1fb26c8b690cc772e537d5762189af78) of what a smaller reproduction would look like.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I didn't know if the CSV code was relevent because I didn't have any idea what was causing the error. The duplicate was confusing to me because none of the example code for Rusqlite ever used "&ToSql" and it still worked, so the example might have fixed the problem but without me understanding why it happened. I'll be sure to check out the mentioned resources!

Comment: You don't have to know what's causing the error to delete code and see if the error continues. That's the process for creating a MRE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`rusqlite::params`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.21.0/rusqlite/macro.params.html) macro solves the problem:

```
use rusqlite::{params, Connection, Result};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    // ...

    for record in reader.records() {
        // ...

        conn.execute(
            "INSERT INTO merchants (name, billing_portal, billing_period, stripe_id)
             values (?, ?, ?, ?)",
            params![
                &merch.name,
                &merch.billing_portal,
                &merch.billing_period,
                &merch.stripe_id,
            ],
        )
        .expect("Error inserting merchant into database");
    }

    Ok(())
}
```