# How to explicitly annotate the type of an array literal

Tags: rust

I have this Rusqlite code:

```
use rusqlite::types::ToSql;

// ... normal Rusqlite initialisation code ...

let mut statement = tx.prepare("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?1, ?2)")?;
let params: &[&dyn ToSql] = &[
    &0u32,
    &"hello",
];
statement.execute(params)?;
```

The `?1` parameter is an `INTEGER` and the `?2` parameter is `TEXT`. This compiles, however if I move the `params` into the function call it does not compile:

```
statement.execute(&[
    &0u32,
    &"hello",
])?;
```

This gives the following error for `&hello`.

```
mismatched types
  expected type `&u32`
found reference `&&'static str`
```

It seems like it infers the type for the array literal based on the type of the first element. What is the syntax for explicitly setting the type of the array?

Comment: try with as  `&[&0u32 as &dyn ToSql, &"hello" as &dyn ToSql]` ?

Comment: I think you only need to coerce the first array element to `&dyn ToSql`.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: See also [Why does Rusqlite reject the Option type when executing a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59900003/155423); [Cannot call rusqlite's query because it expects the type &[&rusqlite::types::ToSql\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46624591/155423).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You annotate the type of an array literal the same way as any other type, by writing the type after the variable name, separated by a colon:

```rust
let array: [u8; 5] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

That's not your problem. Your problem is that you are creating a heterogeneous array, one where the types of each element differ. The first element is a reference to an integer, the second a string, etc. You need to perform the case to the trait object more eagerly:

```rust
let x = [&42 as &dyn Display, &true];
```

For rusqlite specifically, use the [`params!`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.23.1/rusqlite/macro.params.html) macro to do this for you:

```rust
use rusqlite::params; // 0.23.1

fn main() {
    let x = params![&42, &true];
}
```

See also:

- [How to create a vector of boxed closures in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49012277/155423)
- [Use Option::map to Box::new a trait object does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48864045/155423)
- [How to coerce a Vec of structs to a Vec of trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58683548/155423)
- [Why does Rusqlite reject the Option type when executing a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59900003/155423)
- [Cannot call rusqlite's query because it expects the type &[&rusqlite::types::ToSql]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46624591/155423)

Comment: So to be clear, there is no explicit syntax; it just uses the type of the first element.